# Is it normal that every HTTP request is executed twice using Alamofire? One without the authorization header and the other with it?

Tags: ios, swift, http, http-headers, alamofire

When I execute an HTTP request with an **authorization token** as a **header**, using **Alamofire**, the request is executed **twice**:

1) the first execution **without** the authorization, gets a **401** status code

2) the second **with** the authorization included, gets the expected **200**

Is that normal or is that a bug?
If that is normal, could that be disabled? Is that recommended?

```
    myNewRequest.headers["Authorization"] = token

    SessionManager.default.request(newRequest)
    .validate()
    .response(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { _ in
        // handle request
    }
```

Comment: let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/headers", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
} 

Did you try standard way like in doc ?, not session manager